# Problem with oEmbed in some themes

Tags: oembed

I registered my oembed provider, in my wp cms (provider is not whitelisted in WP community). But I have problems with this oembed url. Mentioned oembed url is working in some themes, and in other I get message “not-embeddable”.

I tried adding oembed provider to class-omebed.php as it is in file. Also I tried using wp_oembed_add_provider() in functions.php file. Results?

Twenty Seventeen: both methods failed.
Twenty Sixteen: worked after adding oembed provider to class-omebed.php file. I even didn’t had to set reject_unsafe_urls = false.

Structure of oembed url: http://embed.somedomain.com/oembed/1tkd4423u13hv1v090s6nbfg51/80b20ddf133a22bda080008e3d

Can anyone help me solve this problem?
Maybe someone know this issue?
Maybe adding omebed to whitelist of wp community will help?

Answer (score 0):

For interested parties. Solution of my (and maybe similar problems) was to check headers of oembed feed. I didn't notice that my headers where little different that in RFC :) Fixing them helped me with my problem.